# ubicar elemento en diccionario Python

Tags: python

Tengo que buscar el elemento 30 en el siguiente diccionario en *Python*

```
['a', 'b', {'foo': 1, 'bar': {'x': 10, 'y': 20, 'z': 30}, 'baz': 3}, 'c', 'd']
```

No entiendo como moverme dentro del diccionario hasta llegar al 30.

Desde ya muchas gracias.

Saludos

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con _ubicar elemento_? ¿Obtener el índice? ¿Obtener el nombre de indexación ("z")?

Comment: No es diccionario; es una lista con diversos elementos. Uno de ellos es un diccionario. Comienza por escribir un código que recorra la lista examinando cada elemento hasta encontrar el diccionario.

Comment: Luego edita tu pregunta para agregar el código que escribiste. Agregalo como texto, no como imagen.

Comment: Mi bola de cristal mágica me dice que lo que tiene que hacer el OP no es buscar el 30, sino escribir con qué sintaxis se accedería a ese elemento. Es decir, si la lista que se muestra está guardada en una variable `d`, la respuesta sería `d[2]['bar']['z']`. @Andres dime si le tengo que cambiar ya las pilas a mi bola ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Acá te dejo un ejemplo de como buscar el número 30, sea en los valores de la lista que en los valores de ambos diccionarios.

```
lista = ['a', 'b', {'foo': 1, 'bar': {'x': 10, 'y': 20, 'z': 30}, 'baz': 3}, 'c', 'd', 3]

for e in lista:
    # itera en los elementos de la lista
    if 30 == e:
        pass # elemento encontrado en la lista
    try:
        for v in e.values():
            # itera en los valores de los diccionarios en la lista
            if 30 == v:
                pass # elemento encontrado en el primer diccionario
            try:
                for d in v.values():
                    # itera en los valores del diccionario valor del otro diccionario
                    if 30 == d:
                        pass # elemento encontrado en el segundo diccionario
            except:
                # evita error en caso de que el elemento no sea un diccionario
                pass
    except:
        # evita error en caso de que el elemento no sea un diccionario
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Una solución recursiva.

La función `buscar` recibe un objeto cualquiera. Si es una lista, recorre sus elementos examinando cada uno recursivamente.

Si es un diccionario, examina los valores recursivamente (pueden ser lista u otros diccionarios).

Cuando el valor es un entero, lo compara con 30 y retorna la llave correspondiente.

En cualquier otro caso, retorna `None`, señalando que el valor buscado no está ahí.

```
a=['a', 'b', {'foo': 1, 'bar': {'x': 10, 'y': 20, 'z': 30}, 'baz': 3}, 'c', 'd']

def buscar(objeto):
    if type(objeto) == list:
        for elemento in objeto:
            resultado = buscar(elemento)
            if resultado:
                return resultado
    elif type(objeto) == dict:
        for key, value in objeto.items():
            if type(value) == int:
                if value == 30:
                    return key
            else:
                resultado = buscar(value)
                if resultado:
                    return resultado
    else:
        return None

print("La llave del valor 30 es:", buscar(a))
```

produce:

```
La llave del valor 30 es: z
```